# Order Details Email (From Customer Email Address)

Tags: orders, email

I'm looking to change the from email address that is visible in the Order details email sent to the store when an order is placed. The store wants this to be the address of the customer to make replying easier. Can this be specified through Magento Admin or do the files need changing/is an extension needed?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a good e-mail client and they press `reply all` it will add the customer in the `To` address.

If it is a alias e-mail address for a global mailbox it will also add itself, but that can easily be solved adding the identities correctly to the e-mail client.

The problem is that when you will change this, the customer will get a e-mail from itself and cannot reply anymore.